# When is the approximation of neglecting the surface energy most useful during estimating the total energy of a spherical system?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, surface-tension, approximations

The bulk energy of a spherical system of radius R is proportional to its volume and the surface energy is proportional to its area. The surface energy per unit area, S, and bulk energy per unit volume, u, of the system are characteristic properties of the system that are constant at a given temperature and vary as $S=aT^{1/2}$ and   $u=bT$. In estimating the total energy the approximation of neglecting the surface energy is best when:

A) Both R and T are large
B) R is large and T is small
C) R is small and T is large
D) Both R and T is small

I can't understand how to proceed to make the approximation. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The total energy of the spherical system is
$$E=aT^{\frac {1}{2}}4\pi R^2+bT\frac {4}{3}\pi R^3=bT\frac {4}{3}\pi R^3(1+\frac {3a}{bR\sqrt {T}})$$
The second term in brackets will be small compared to 1 if $R\sqrt {T}>>1$. This is best done when $R>>1$ and $T>>1$.